# How do I set minumum password requirements in Umbraco for the membership provider?

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-2.0, membership-provider, umbraco

I am trying to set minimum password requirements for my membership provider in Umbraco. Currently my web.config membership section looks like this:

```
   <membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" />
        <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

However, when I login in through the website and change my password, it will let me use a password of any length and makeup. Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically custom membership provider settings are passed as custom xml attributes on the  tag itself. You can see one there already: "userIsOnlineTimeWindow." Fire up Reflector and have a dig around the Assembly containing that provider, or praise-jeebus, RTFM. :D

-Oisin

Comment: Manuals? Who reads manuals? j/k Yeah, I've been all over Umbraco's forum and MSDN with to no avail. Figured I'd go to source of all knowledge, SO, before I trudge through endless search results on Google.