# How to Change Password Requirements for Admins on Umbraco 4

Tags: asp.net, security, passwords, umbraco

Sorry in advance, but I read the answer to this post, and I don't get it. I don't know what reflector is either, other than something that lets you stream your device.

[How do I set minumum password requirements in Umbraco for the membership provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651816/how-do-i-set-minumum-password-requirements-in-umbraco-for-the-membership-provide)

The website link above does not help me. How can I make the changes I need to make to change the password requirements for Umbraco 4?

I've posted on Umbraco - but not getting much help there...

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/87361-password-requirements-for-admin-login

Any assistance would be great.

Here's the code I currently am using:

out. I can still login easy and quickly. Can you help? Here's what I have so far:

```html
out. I can still login easy and quickly. Can you help? Here's what I have so far: 
 <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" passwordAnswerAttemptLockoutDuration="30" passwordAttemptWindow="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
<add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" passwordAnswerAttemptLockoutDuration="30" passwordAttemptWindow="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
```

Comment: Could ypu perhaps elaborate on what you're trying to do - which requirements you need to change? And what you've tried?

Comment: Sure. I wanted to change invalid password attempts to 3, a lockout duration, change the minimum password length requirement, and make it alpha numeric. The code above is what I have tried. But whenever I make a change or use even the code above, nothing works. I can still login with any password regardless of what password requirements I set in place. It also doesn't lockout at all.